# Assigning processor to a Grand Central Dispatch queue

Tags: cocoa, grand-central-dispatch

Is it possible to assign processor's core to a specific GCD queue or to a function that is launched by that queue?

If yes, then how could it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Nope. That's fundamentally antithetical to the purpose of GCD.

Comment: Why is it antithetical?

Comment: GCD's purpose is to do all of the management of scheduling work from many queues in the most efficient way possible. You're asking to dedicate an entire core to one queue or function, which sidesteps GCD doing the management, and fundamentally defeats the efficiency in how multiple queues are able to *share* the cores so that all of the work gets done efficiently. If multiple processes all said "give me a core for this specific thing" then soon there'd be no cores left. GCD aside, that's where the difference between cooperative and preemptive thread models comes in.